# Oracle database error (ORA-12505, ORA-01078, ORA-00600)

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, ora-00600, ora-01034, ora-27101

I am a beginner who has just begun to study Spring. And I'm using Boot Camp on a MacBook. I am having a problem linking SQL Developer to my database.

I downloaded Oracle 11g Express Edition and SQL Developer to link Oracle database to use STS. But an ORA-12505 error occurred in SQL Developer when I tried to connect.

To solve that I tried to run SQL*Plus but got ORA-01034 and ORA-27101 errors (I think caused by the database being shut down). To solve those errors, I tried the following.

```
sqlplus /nolog
conn sys/as sysdba
```

which said "Connected to an idle instance", so I tried:

```
shutdown abort
startup
```

but that got:

```
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kspifisp:ksfdread_resilver], [0x000A9FA68],
           [0x000A9F800], [512], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []"
```

I tried

```
show parameter undo
```

but that just got "ORA-01034 ORACLE not available" again.

I don't know where it's wrong because of so many errors. I think the root of all this error is the lack of `spfile`, but I haven't found a solution to it.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The alert log should give you more information about which parameter value it wasn't happy about. [This could be relevant](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/258951/847), or you could be hitting [this bug](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1575865_1.html). Either way this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.